# Missing database and measurements in kapacitor

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, kapacitor

Kapacitor version is 1.5.4
InfluxDB version is 1.7.6

Deployed influx DB and kapacitor in kubernetes(in 2 different clusters). Not able to view the influxDB database and measurements in kapacitor. All I see are the default ones(kapacitor stats ingress)

_kapacitor as the database name, autogen as the retention policy and kapacitor, ingress, runtime as the measurements.

How to debug this issue?

Comment: Did you check kapacitor logs? Made sure it can connect to influx in the other cluster? Can you connect to the influx db from outside the cluster using the same credentials you've fed kapacitor?

Comment: Yes, In which ever cluster I have installed Kapacitor, I did tried to connect influx DB using CURL and I was getting results.

Comment: How have you deployed those? Have you checked if pods are running? Have you created the service to expose those deployments?

Comment: https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/kapacitor/templates .. I used the helm charts to create Kapacitor deployment and Service files. I see the Kapacitor POD up and running. The influx DB POD has been running for a long time. Should I mention the Kapacitor URL somewhere in the influxDB conf file? I dont have telegraf as part of this setup should I have that too?

Comment: This issue is resolved, I installed both influxDB and Kapacitor in the same cluster.